# Execute a function periodically in python for every n milliseconds in python 2

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm wondering how to execute a function in Python for every 10ms. I tried with threading (using `threading.Timer(0.001, fun)`), but `threading.Timer` executes properly only up to seconds. Is there any to execute a task/function in ms(milli seconds)?

The code is as follows.

```
def task():
    print "called every 10ms"
    print time.ctime()
    threading.Timer(0.01,task).start()

task()
```

Comment: it's `threading.Timer`, right ? The code looks fine to me - what is the output you get?

Comment: 10 ms is somewhat fast. Are you sure that Python is what you need if need this kind of control?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.yes it's threading.Timer                                              If it gets executes for every 10ms the print statement should print 100 times for every second.But the output is different in different systems.The print statement is not getting printed 100 times for every 1 second

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim yes,I want to execute a task less than milliseconds(500 microseconds) but I am not getting proper output even for milliseconds.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Doing something over 1000 times a second? Only thing that comes in my mind is a DDoS attack... ^^

Comment: I want to send a message with periodicity of 10 millisecond  to a device connected to the pc @DanielFrühauf

Comment: Are you testing this with a print statement? Scrolling and handling the terminal will significantly slow things down. Why don't you just run  your `send_message_to_device` function inside a for loop with a `usleep` to make sure that it's not faster than 1000 times a second.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I will try that..thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it on my own and it works, but it seems that Python isn't that fast in the console. In my case it just gets to about 60 runs per second.

```
import threading
import time

def hello(*args):
    print(str(args[0])+" It's "+str(time.ctime()))
    next=int(args[0])+1
    threading.Timer(0.001, hello,[str(next)]).start()

hello("1")
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but this looks like the hello() function is recursive - probably not what you want? (this question is old, so I'm sure you've long since figured it out)

Comment: @RalphBolton a recursive function by definition is one that calls itself. hello() does not call itself. It passes itself as an argument to the Timer constructor

Comment: What if the function takes 5ms to run, then wouldn't this call it every 6ms?

Comment: @AaronFranke yes in this example it would take 6ms. Because it schedules next call only after the function is run.

Answer (score 4):

I also had a similar problem in which I needed to do some sampling at 1000Hz and that couldn't have any considerable drift on the long run. Trying to sleep 0.001 seconds would always result in a lower sampling rate (drifting), even when I tried to estimate the time the sampling code took to execute (with a time.time() after and before sleeping).

It turns out that a simple solution is to keep track of the number of executions and use it to calculate if you are late or not.

```py
import time
import threading

class PeriodicSleeper(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task_function, period):
        super().__init__()
        self.task_function = task_function
        self.period = period
        self.i = 0
        self.t0 = time.time()
        self.start()

    def sleep(self):
        self.i += 1
        delta = self.t0 + self.period * self.i - time.time()
        if delta > 0:
            time.sleep(delta)
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.task_function()
            self.sleep()
```

And for testing:

```
def task():
    t = time.time()
    if abs(t - round(t)) <= 0.0005:
        print(t, 'Mean Frequency:', sleeper.i / (t - sleeper.t0))

sleeper = PeriodicSleeper(task, 0.001)
```

Resulting in a deviation that is less than half a period and a mean frequency that converges to the desired value.

```
1623373581.0000355 Mean Frequency: 999.8594124106243
1623373582.0000308 Mean Frequency: 999.9576212826602
1623373583.0000248 Mean Frequency: 999.9771123402633
1623373584.0000222 Mean Frequency: 999.9844427446347
1623373585.0000298 Mean Frequency: 999.9862123585227
1623373586.000023 Mean Frequency: 999.989990000442
....
1623373863.0000231 Mean Frequency: 999.9998049640523
1623373864.000024 Mean Frequency: 999.9998022878916
1623373865.0000224 Mean Frequency: 999.9998088494829
1623373866.0000248 Mean Frequency: 999.9998011675633
```

Comment: Theoretically for a very long and very frequent process, wouldn't the number of executions overflow? If so - is it feasible to reset it for large values?

Comment: Python integers don't overflow, they have variable length, so there is no need to worry.